# Response method doesnt working properly in php script

Tags: php, android, response, android-volley

I make a project in android studio for login/register.
I use volley library and a php script that connects my java code with my database.The POST method working perfectly and i can insert information in my database.But i get nothing on response.Seems there is an error in my php script.
Here is the php script:

```
   $con = mysqli_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com", "a3288368_user", "abcd1234", "a3288368_data");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: it is better to `var_export($response)` to a file on the server to see what is its content (if you can debug it, then for sure use a debugger with a breakpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
print_r(json_encode($response));
```

You can't echo json string.

Comment: It is possible to echo anything. print_r() is just a matter of rendering an array (which a matter of PHP). Echo sends a [pack] of content back to the client.

Comment: Exactly, i meant to say a user has to call that [pack] of data only in order to get the result using echo not the entire json string. Please correct me if i am wrong.
He could use : `echo $response['success'];`

Comment: When you `json_encode()` you are making an string. That string is meaningful only to a JSON parser, else, it is just an string as "Hello World" is a string [of characters].
What you say is true if the user didn't want to `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

Before echoing out the response, you should set a JSON header:

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

This tells the HTTP client to expect a JSON type of content.

Comment: I am using volley library.Seems not working for volley